# How to install wireless drivers without internet access?

Tags: linux, drivers, broadcom

I have a wireless card that needs the Broadcom B4311 Rev. 1 driver but I don't have a way to download that driver since I don't have wireless access since the driver isn't installed.

I'm running Linux Mint Debian x64.

Comment: probably going to be b43 or ndiswrapper...i stick with aetheros

Comment: you could boot backtrack live and download that way...i think it supports broadcom out of the box...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download a few files from another computer and install the firmware.

Ignore the `wget`'s, just put the corresponding file in the working directory instead of launching the command.

There are instructions here
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43

For a similar chip (which probably uses the same firmware) there are more straightforward instructions:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/Laptop/Lucid/Reports/AcerAspireOneD150#Post-install%20fixes

Answer (score 1):

Been in this exact situation with my E1505. Easiest way is to go out and buy a network card to plug in, and then return the card.

But if that's not an option, you can follow the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20No%20Internet%20access), but make sure to replace any reference to Ubuntu with Debian.