# Ethernet driver missing

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, desktop-computer

I've recently purchased a new tower, and I've started setting it up today. I installed Windows 7 and booted it up, but I can't download/update drivers automatically because I don't have internet and I don't have internet because I can't get the drivers...

Specs are AMD APU A4 Dual core 7300, 8gb ddr3 ram, All-in-one A88X Chipset FM2+ motherboard, and a 300Mbps USB WiFi adapter dongle. I'm also wired to my router.

What should I manually download, or can I get them automatically somehow?

Comment: Go to the OEM's website, look up the model, download all drivers related to your computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install wireless drivers without internet access?](http://superuser.com/questions/229602/how-to-install-wireless-drivers-without-internet-access)

Comment: Get a thumb drive and download the required drivers on a working internet connection.